# (MFC) all pop-up windows including AfxMessageBox, Dialog and File Explorer are behind of main window

Tags: mfc

As I wrote in the title, all the pop-up messages are hidden behind of main window which I created it as a SDI(Single Document Interface) form and added Office 2007 style to it.

I tried to use `::MessageBox` instead of `AfxMessageBox` and `SetWindowPos` function to fix a z-order to  bottom but it's not worked.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a hidden top-level parent. Put a breakpoint inside `CWinApp::DoMessageBox` and check which parent window your popup is assigned!